# Can't use SSH at all

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, openssh

I'm having some problems when trying to use the command ssh-copy-id in my server, unfortunately I get the following response:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.10.10 port 22: Connection refused
```

I can't find out what is happening, even though I tried many solutions. I've installed `openssh-client` on the client and `openssh-server` on the server, can anyone help me please?

Comment: check if sshd is working or not. use netstat -lpn | grep ":22"

Answer (score 1):

*The debugging steps should be as follows*

1. Check if you both are on the same network by doing a ping test

   ***ping <ip address>***
2. Now check if the ssh daemon is working or not by using the netstat command

   ***netstat -lpn | grep ":22"***

If true is answer for the above steps , the connection should work.

Comment: Ping is working both ways and netstat shows that there are no problems, but I still can't use the SSH. Thanks

Comment: So netstat shows that you have port 22 used by ssh ?

Comment: try this on the machine you want to connect , sudo service iptables stop

Comment: Yes, it says its listening. Still not really working, I'm also getting a message: "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED".

Comment: Also, when trying another client, the passwords don't work, even though they are correct... I'm trying to use ssh-copy-id and it says that permission is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

I needed to add a password for root... The command I used is:

> sudo passwd root

Comment: Instead you should make a user (NOT ROOT) any other user and login via that. If mandatory then its okay to login via root.

If not via root, you should login via ssh user@ip:port